# Vue.js - show more objects from array if they have same title

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have an array of objects:

```
[{ 
   title: 'foo'
   id: 1,
   name: 'anne'
 },
  
 { 
   title: 'example',
   id: 2,
   name: 'anne'
 },
 { 
   title: 'ex',
   id: 3,
   name: 'deb'
 }]
```

The page is already showing the first object:

```
{ 
   title: 'foo'
   id: 1,
   name: 'anne'
 },
 
 <div class="essay">
   <p class="title" >{{ selectedItem.title }}</p>
   <p class="id">{{ selectedItem.id }}</p>
   <p class="name"> {{ selectedItem.name }} </p>
 </div>
```

`selectedItem` comes from the `created()` life cycle

What is the best way to display the object with the same name?

I want to have a button which if clicked, will show another title from the person name `'anne'`.

Comment: *The page is already showing the first object* how have you did that?

Comment: Please add your code for component which shows one object, then I can understand the problem

Comment: done, let me know if more is needed

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the filtered array.

```
created() {
  this.selectedItem = arr.filter(item => item.name === 'anne');
  // arr is the array source variable.
}
```

```
 <div v-for="item in selectedItem" :key="item.id" class="essay">
   <p class="title" >{{ selectedItem.title }}</p>
   <p class="id">{{ selectedItem.id }}</p>
   <p class="name"> {{ selectedItem.name }} </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a snippet, maybe it would help You :-)

We need to store state somewhere, so I've created `owners` variable with `shown` counter.

There is also a computed property that groups items by owners.

Maybe there is an easier method but...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      { owner: "John", name: "Box" },
      { owner: "John", name: "Keyboard" },
      { owner: "John", name: "Plate" },
      { owner: "Ann", name: "Flower" },
      { owner: "Ann", name: "Cup" }
    ],
    owners: {},
  },
  methods: {
    more(owner) {
      if (this.owners[owner].shown < this.items.filter(i => i.owner == owner).length) {
        this.owners[owner].shown++;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ownersItems() {
      let map = {};
      this.items.forEach(i => {
        map[i.owner] = map[i.owner] || [];
        if (this.owners[i.owner].shown > map[i.owner].length) {
          map[i.owner].push(i);
        }
      });
      return map;
    },
  },
  created() {
    let owners = {};
    this.items.forEach(i => {
      owners[i.owner] = owners[i.owner] || {};
      owners[i.owner].shown = 1;
    });
    this.owners = owners;
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
sup {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .15rem;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  font-size: 75%;
}
.btn {
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: .15rem;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="header">Owners</div>
  <template v-for="(cfg, owner) in owners">
    <strong>{{ owner }} <sup>{{cfg.shown}}</sup>:</strong>
    <a v-for="(item, i) in ownersItems[owner]" :key="`${owner}_${i}`" @click="more(owner)" class="btn">{{ item.name }}</a>
    |
  </template>
</div>
```